# Paragraphs field preprocess hook not called

Tags: 9, paragraphs

To simplify this issue, I just have 2 hooks:

```
1. customtheme_preprocess_paragraph__registration_button()
2. customtheme_preprocess_paragraph__registration_button__default()
```

When I access a node with a registration button with a default view mode, only the first hook is called.
Also, when I access the `$variables['view_mode']` in that hook, it gives the value 'default'.

Furthermore, it only takes the paragraph--registration-button.html.twig as template, but not paragraph--registration-button--default.html.twig

I am using Drupal Core 9.5.4 and Paragraphs 1.15.0.
Could this be something in my setup?

Comment: `default` view mode is used as placeholder value for empty, unset... It seems very weird to overwrite the default template with another default template.

Comment: This happened for every view mode, no matter the name. For example, the sidebar view mode did not trigger the customtheme_preprocess_paragraph__registration_button__sidebar() hook, nor did it show the paragraph--registration-button--sidebar.html.twig template. Instead it is using the basic hook without any view modes and the basic template, as written in the description above.

Comment: If I recall correctly, that's a bug in Paragraphs. It was a few years ago at least.

Comment: Does this hook exist at all? I know of `hook_preprocess_paragraph__BUNDLE()`, but I've never used a `hook_preprocess_paragraph__VIEWMODE()`

Comment: Just to be totally sure, you've cleared caches?

Comment: I tested this out and found I could implement hook_preprocess_HOOK() for the default view mode of a paragraph and it is called. When you turn on Twig debugging and look at the "FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS" in HTML comments, do you see paragraph--registration-button--default.html.twig? I do.

Comment: Yes, indeed, I do see the twig suggestion in twig debug, but I do not know what happened after I updated PHP 7.4 --> PHP 8.1 and Drupal Core 9.3 --> 9.5, as well as Paragraphs module 1.12.0 --> 1.15.0. Now the view mode hooks are not triggered for any paragraph, as well as the templates are not displayed.

Comment: Found the issue, it was a custom patch that was changing the order of the template suggestions in function paragraphs_theme. Closing this because it is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be closed, it was a custom setup.